# Why are my inputs and outputs not the same dimensions for my autoencoder (keras)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using keras's ImageDataGenerator to load in the images I need, and I am almost sure I did everything right. However, when I run model.fit, I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [32,256,256,4] vs. [32,256,256,3]
     [[node gradient_tape/mean_squared_error/BroadcastGradientArgs (defined at <ipython-input-40-df574b708cf9>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3030]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I can't comprehend why this is. The images are definitely only 3-channeled.

Here is where I define my ImageDataGenerator:

```
datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.,
                                                         validation_split=.2,
                                                         horizontal_flip=True,
                                                         rotation_range=20)
```

And here is where I define my training and test generator:

```
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory('./lfw-funneled/lfw_funneled', shuffle=True, seed=1337, subset='training', class_mode='input', color_mode='rgb')
test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory('./lfw-funneled/lfw_funneled', shuffle=True, seed=1337, subset='validation', class_mode='input', color_mode='rgb')
```

I even included the `color_mode='rgb'` even though thats the default setting, just to be sure.

And here is the code that I use to ensure that the images are the same and of the same dimensions.

```
val = test_generator.__next__()
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(val[0][0])
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(val[1][0])
print(val[0][0].shape, val[1][0].shape) # prints out (256, 256, 3), (256, 256, 3)
```

Yet, calling the fit function yields the exception listed above.

```
ae.fit(train_generator,
      validation_data=test_generator)
```

Anyone know what could be causing this error? I think every snippet of code I listed here should be fine... Thank you!

Comment: Does the output layer of your model have 4 channels?

Comment: @ArvinKushwaha Oh my, yes it does. I had a Conv2DTranspose as my last layer and it had 4 filter maps. Didn't even cross my mind. Thanks a lot haha!

Comment: Oh, that's great! Good luck with your autoencoder!